# How send message on websocket server to specific user( s)

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm reading up on websockets and after reading a lot of tutorials and blogs (mostly about creating a simple chat application) there is still 1 question unanswered :

Type of technology used aside (node.js or php of python) I find no way of sending a message to 1 user or a group of users without first getting an event of the client to the websocket server ( often called onconnect() or onmessage() ).

Is it then not possible to have some external application or event call some script (bash or php) that uses the existing running websocket instance to send/broadcast some information (text) to one or more connected browsers (websocket clients) ??

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I am not able to find an answer by reading these blogs on the web.

Thank you for this clarification.

Comment: if someone didnt connect you obviously cant send him a message?

Comment: You mean you just want to hack into already running server and just send info, or I am missing something? :) 
If you mean if you want to move the sending function **outside** of the `on connect` handler - of course you can!

Comment: I know there most first be a connect() from a websocket client. So far I understand. And on this connect() I could send a reply from the websocket server like 'welcome user !'. But then... that's my bottom question : what if I - websocket server - want to send a second message to this user 'user, do you know you are still connected ?'. How do I send this second message without the websocket user sending something to the websocket server first ?? Not interesting in hacking something here, this is a serious question.

Comment: @Andrey Popov : you say "of course you can!" Can you tell me just how or point me to a tutorial that explains this ?

Comment: The only working solution I have come up with so far is to make my external application also a websocket client subscribed to the websocket server. I just execute some other logic when the ID of my external application send a message.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've understand, you can easily use sockets like:

```
// main.js
this.sockets = {};
myOtherModule.init(sockets);
io.on('connection', function(socket)) {
    sockets[socket.id] = socket;

    socket.on('command', myOtherModule.onSocketCommand);
}


// myOtherModule.js
this.init = function(sockets) {
    this.sockets = sockets;
}
this.onSocketCommand = function() {
    this.sockets['other.socket.id'].emit('message');
}
```

You can always save the socket somewhere, no matter if it's within object or single variable. Then you can always use it to emit messages.